Why does SQL Server not use a parallel execution plan to load all rows from a large table?
If I populate a table with this definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GpsData]
(
    [GpsDataID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UnitID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Longitude] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Latitude] [float] NOT NULL,
    [GpsTimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SpeedKmpH] [tinyint] NULL,
    [OdoKm] [float] NULL,
    [DataStatusID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GpsDataID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

with 2 million rows, I get parallel execution plans for:
SELECT * 
FROM GpsData 
WHERE GpsDataID < 3000

and for
SELECT * 
FROM GpsData 
WHERE GpsDataID % 2 = 0 OR GpsdataID % 2 = 1

and for
SELECT * 
FROM GpsData 
WHERE Longitude > 1

but not for:
SELECT * FROM GpsData

Surely for the last one, there could be multiple workers scanning the table, each returning a part of it?

Please share all execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/craigfr/parallel-scan#:~:text=We%20get%20a%20serial%20plan!%C2%A0%20Why%20don%E2%80%99t%20we%20get%20a%20parallel%20plan%3F

The folks doing query-plan optimization for SQL Server having been doing it for over a quarter-century, so it's a good guess that they know parallelism won't help your full-table query.
Your table doesn't have any BLOBs or CLOBs (large objects) so the whole thing is stored in the clustered primary key. Satisfying your query is a matter of scanning that clustered primary key sequentially, formatting the data, and pushing it out the network connection to your client software.  The bottlenecks are storage IO (reading the CPK) and network IO (pushing the data) and it seems likely CPU parallelism won't do anything to help those bottlenecks.
In SSMS, right click on the query window and choose Show Actual Execution Plan. You'll learn a lot.
